# Loop in xml file?

Tags: xml, loops

In my XML file, I need to specify points like:

```
  <Point x1="1.4" x2="50.0" phase="1" y="0.0" />

  <Point x1="1.8" x2="50.0" phase="1" y="0.0" />

  <Point x1="2.2" x2="50.0" phase="1" y="0.0" />
```

ect.

If I want to generate the same set of points where x1 is the same, but x2 changes to 100, how could I do that?

It would be quite tedious to go through and write each point out, since I would want to do hundreds of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is a data format, not a programming language.

To read or write XML, use a programming language, preferably with an XML library.  Reading XML is best done with an XML parser.

It is in the programming language where the concept iteration (looping) applies.

Note that some programming languages such as XSLT use XML as their syntax.  Ant uses XML as its syntax for expressing build dependencies and processes.  Still, here you'd not ask how to use `loop` in XML but rather in XSLT or Ant or whatever programming language is leveraging XML as its syntax.

Finally, consider search-and-replace in a text or XML editor.